# Angular blocks script tags in template

Tags: angular, xss

I have a script tag which comes from backend as a string:

```
<script>
(function(){
var a = document.createElement("script");
a.type="text/javascript";
a.src="https://someurl.js";
</script>
```

I want to add to div as innerHTML.

```
<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>
```

Angular blocks it. What is the solution?

Comment: I think you need to dynamically create a component to compile it: https://medium.com/@lukaonik/how-to-create-dynamic-components-in-angular-a2f449acb987

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To input **HTML** in some component you must to use **DomSanitizer**, like this:

```
data:SafeHtml;
constructor(private sanitizer: DomSanitizer) { ... }

yourFunction() {
  this.data = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(YOUR_STRING_HTML)
}
```

In component it's right.

```
<div [innerHTML]="data"></div>
```

Comment: This should use the `bypassSecurityTrustScript()` method.

Answer (score 0):

You can inject dynamic HTML using **DomSanitizer** service of Angular. DomSanitizer modifies the input and turns into a value that is safe to insert into the DOM. Use **bypassSecurityTrustHtml** of **DOMSanitizer** to bypass this security check.

```js
  trustedHtml: any;
  unsafeHtml: any;

  constructor(private domSanitizer: DomSanitizer) {
    this.unsafeHtml = `<script>
                        (function(){
                        var a = document.createElement("script");
                        a.type="text/javascript";
                        a.src="https://someurl.js";
                      </script>`;
    this.trustedHtml =    this.domSanitizer.sanitize(SecurityContext.HTML,this.domSanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustHtml(this.unsafeHtml));
  }
```

```html
<div [innerHtml]="trustedHtml">  </div>
```

[Live Example here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-domsanitizer-example?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: This should use the `bypassSecurityTrustScript()` method.

Answer (score 0):

**bypassSecurityTrustScript** NOT **bypassSecurityTrustHtml**

Angular by default blocks this due to the [following](https://angular.io/guide/security#sanitization-example):

> Angular sanitizes untrusted values for HTML, styles, and URLs; sanitizing resource URLs isn't possible because they contain arbitrary code. In development mode, Angular prints a console warning when it has to change a value during sanitization.

This is important, because without this, untrusted values could be ran in our applications, as malicious scripts. This is known as a Cross Site Scripting attack, in which an attacker finds a way to inject a value in an application.

**If you are certain that this endpoint will only return this script** (I would be cautious if you don't have control over this endpoint), then use the `DomSanitizer` method to bypass this default behaviour by Angular:

```
this.yourService().subscribe((script) => {
    this.script = this.sanitizer.bypassSecurityTrustScript(script);
});
```

This method returns a [SafeScript](https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/SafeScript), which tells Angular that it's safe to use as JavaScript.

Answer (score -1):

You can do it in such way.

```
const divEl = this.canvasElRef.nativeElement;

const scriptEl = this.renderer2.createElement('script');
    scriptEl.type = 'text/javascript';
    scriptEl.text = `
      (function() {
        console.log('console!')
      }());
    `;
    
this.renderer2.appendChild(divEl, scriptEl);
```